# JQuery concatenate multiple :not selector

Tags: jquery, scroll, carousel

I have multiple Bootstrap Carousels in one page and I'm also using JQuery Smooth Scroll so I'm trying to add more :not selectors to the JQuery Smooth function to not target my carousels:

```
jQuery('a[href*=#]:not([href="#carousel-custom"]):not([href="#carousel-custom-three"])').on('click.scroll', function() {
```

The function works fine when I add the first :not but it doesn't work as soon as I add the second :not. I tried all the other relevant Stackoverflow questions and answers but unfortunately no answer is working for me.

I'm not a JQuery expert, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Your selector works for me https://jsfiddle.net/3f41u3w8/

Comment: Sometimes using the `.not()` method makes it easier to read, still the same as what you have though -> `jQuery('a[href*=#]').not('[href="#carousel-custom"],[href="#carousel-custom-three"]')`

Comment: And note that you're doing straight match, the href has to have those values exactly, to be excluded.

Comment: or if all your carousel links starts the href with **#carousel...** then use something like `$('a[href*=#]:not([href^="#carousel"])')`..... https://jsfiddle.net/3f41u3w8/1/

Comment: Make sure there's no spaces before the `:not` in your actual code (there's none in the question, but sometimes actual-vs-question do not match 100%). Which is where using `.not()` can make it easier to manage.

Comment: also check first that you fir the function on click with some console.log ... and chekc your console for errors

Comment: thank you all very much! in the end my own code and the .not() method both worked fine, the problem was on the carousel indicators not pointing to the right ID...